# System.IO.Packaging library does not read standard windows zip files

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, zip, unzip

When reading a zip package using the `System.IO.Packaging` assembly, I have found that zip files created using the standard windows zip utility are unable to be read (the package parts (internal files) of the zip package show as not existing).

After doing some research it appears that this is because the `System.IO.Packaging` library adds a **Content_Types.xml** to the zip when it is created, which does not appear to be present in a standard windows compressed zip.

Example:

```
using (Package Zip = Package.Open(BundlePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    Uri FileUri = PackUriHelper.CreatePartUri(new Uri("somefile.xml", UriKind.Relative));
    if (!Zip.PartExists (FileUri ))  //this fails even though the file exists in the zip
        throw new ResourceException(String.Format("Zip {0} does not contain file", BundlePath));
    ...
```

Is there anyway to still use the packaging system provided by .NET to read standard zip files, or do they need to be created using the library.

**Edit:**

Adding this file (Content_Types.xml) manually, and zipping using the Windows compression utility, proves to be successful in allowing the package to read.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the "standard windows zip utility"?

Comment: @Oded - The default compression utility that comes with Windows XP, Windows 7, etc

Comment: I will ask again, as I don't know of one that comes with XP.

Comment: @Oded - Perhaps I am mistaken with one being available on XP as I do not have an XP machine in front of me. I currently am using Windows 7.

Comment: @leaf dev: This is quite late, but the "Send To => Compressed Folder" operating in the context menu in Windows Explorer is part of the default utility.  I know for a fact that it's there in Windows Vista and Windows 7.  I think it's there by default in XP too, but I haven't done a fresh XP install in ages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.IO.Packaging` isn't there to read zip files but packages. Use [DotnetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I believe you are correct there isn't a good way to get the System.IO.Packaging libraries to open up any file in a standard zip format that doesn't contain that [content_types].xml file.

I was working on this issue a few months back, and this is what I was trying to implement something that would inject this file before we just decided to initially generate all of our files from within .NET:

the [format of the zip file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29#Structure) is the following

(---file 1---)(---file 2---)...(---file x---)(table of contents)

Without a third party library you should be able to open up a zip file as a binary file, hop to the end and read that table of contents, add a [content_types].xml file at the end with the types/default extension info, adjust the table of contents entries, append it to the end of the file, and go.  The problem I was running into when trying to implement this is there are various checksums on the file to verify that it hasn't been corrupted, I hadn't gotten them all by the time I needed to change directions on this.

I'm sure this is more info that you needed, but should you decide to implement your own solution hopefully this helps.